# How to convert a string to integer in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I want to check whether the content of a variable is an odd number. But I need an integer for it.

```
$ip_array = split($ipaddress, '.')
$odd_ip = $ip_array[3] % 2

if $odd_ip == 1 {
  notice("is odd")
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert a string to integer?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

> $n_timeout = 0 + $timeout

Comment: This breaks with stings with leading zeros, e.g. "04"

Comment: With puppet 4 this will cause a warning: Warning: The string '1' was automatically coerced to the numerical value 1 at ...

Comment: Puppet documentation suggests this, and offers a scanf method to handle extraction versus peer coercion.     https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_data_number.html#reference-5590

Answer (score 3):

I've taken to using the [scanf](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/function.html#scanf) function in stdlib.

An example of this:

$ram = scanf("${::memorysize_mb}", "%i")

This requires puppet >= 3.7.5

Comment: Note that this will return an array, where the first element is the wished value. In puppet 4 it is possible to write something like scanf(...)[0], in puppet 3 it seems to be required to split this in two statements: first assign to an array variable, then get the first element.

Comment: This is acceptable too based on puppet documentation   https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_data_number.html#reference-5590.  Both the @barry above and answers here are allowed by puppetlabs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work exactly as defined; Puppet implicitly converts strings and integers as appropriate for the comparison operator being used.

Comment: I got the following error: Could not match % at /etc/puppet/modules/my/manifests/target.pp:23 on node mynode.domain.de

Comment: If I replace '%' with '*' (testing) -> left operand of * is not a number at /etc/puppet/modules/my/manifests/target.pp:25 on node mynode.domain.de

Comment: Ah.  You have found a genuine bug in Puppet.  You should file a ticket at projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/issues/new so that we can fix it.

Comment: Puppet doesn't do that when the value comes from hiera. You get a "Error 400 on SERVER: comparison of Fixnum with String failed" error.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet 4: `$odd_ip = Integer($ip_array[3]) % 2`

Taken from https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/pull/743/files